# Filtering OLAP Pivot Table based on dates

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, olap

In Excel I have an OLAP-based PivotTable. Each row has a date. I would like the user to be able to change a "start date" field on a control sheet and the table to filter to only dates after the selected date.

If I had the source data, I would simply add a new field that was a boolean for if it was after the selected date.

I tried to accomplish this by using the MDX calculated measure (to create the boolean). I tried using CurrentMember, Value, and several other attributes and also the field itself. The only errors I got did not google well (e.g., greater than or equal to function expects a string or numeric expression a level expression was used). Other times I got errors about Hierarchy expressions. I cannot find these defined in the Microsoft documentation. I also tried setting to 1/0 using the IIf function in case it didn't like Boolean measures.

Is there a way to do this or can the Calculated Measures only be operations on other fields labeled with a Sigma instead of the Menu icon?